# Risk-adjusted returns ratio that does not reward high risk for negative returns

Tags: returns, risk-neutral-measure, performance-evaluation

Think of Sharpe ratio, Treynor ratio, or anything where (excess) returns $r$ are divided by something that represents risk, $\sigma$:

$$\mathrm{performance} = \frac{r}{\sigma}$$

If the returns are negative (let's say for a short period), a performance indicator based on such a ratio is better (=less negative), the higher the risk (e.g. volatility) is.

First question: Does this make sense? I would not say the true performance is better (less poor), if the risk increases – even when the returns are negative.

Second question: Are there established (or even proposed) risk-adjusted return measures that penalize (or at least don't reward) high risk even for negative returns? I'd be quite happy to derive one, but I would expect that someone has already figured this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on both terms - it doesn't make much sense, and there exists a well-cited solution by C. Israelsen: "A refinement to the Sharpe ratio and information ratio." Journal of Asset Management 5.6 (2005): 423-427.

The adjustment he gives is to define $$SR_{adj} = \frac{r}{\sigma^{\frac{r}{abs(r)}}},$$

which solves the ranking problem during periods of negative (excess) return.

Comment: Interesting. This amounts to using $\frac{r}{\sigma}$ if $r>=0$ and $  r \sigma$ otherwise.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for – thanks @Forgottenscience! Also kudos to @noob2 for the clarification. I guess you'd have to be an academic not to prefer the piecewise definition.

Comment: One more problem with the Israelson refinement is left: U would prefer a slight positive performance over a slight negative performance everytime - even when the vol is extremely high for the positive r and low for the negative one! Example:
r in % vol in % r/vol Rank r/vol^(r/abs(r)) Rank 0,01 100,00 0,0001 1 0,0001 1
-0,01 1,00 -0,0100 2 -0,0100 2 But is the positive performance with 100 % vol really better than the negative one...?

Answer (score 3):

1. Does this make sense?  Consider this:  You are an investor.  You have 2 investments.  1 high risk (hr) and the other low risk (lr).  You expect the hr to be volatile and expect the opposite from lr.  If the hr has a small loss and the lr has an equal small loss shouldn't the hr have a better ratio?  It should.  It performed better based on it's volatility and return potential.
2. Yes.  You might consider something like an Omega ratio.  Omega does not assume a normalized distribution of returns and allows you to set a minimum acceptable return.

Using Omega to optimize a portfolio (i.e. assign weightings to each investment) is far more effective than other metrics in helping a manager achieve an expected return of a group of assets.

Answer (score 2):

1) In a certain, theoretical sense, it does make sense: suppose two
   portfolio managers delivered negative returns (-1%, say), and one
   had a higher volatility ("risk") than the other. Then the high-risk fund did better,
   in a way: despite higher risk, the portfolio manager succeeded in
   providing the same small loss as the low-risk manager.

2) I agree that this implies a perverse effect: maximise risk for a
   given negative return. In numerical portfolio
   optimisation, one may rather prefer a linear combination of risk and
   return instead of a ratio, or simply put a 'safeguard' into the
   objective function: when return turns negative, change the
   selection criterion (e.g. select only based on risk).